# Complex Absolute Value Distribution

Tags: complex-numbers

Good Morning. I've seen this property used a few times (by a friend of mine) though I  never really learned it. I've tried to find a counterexample to no avail.

Is the following valid for $w,q,z \in \mathbb{C}$

$$
|w+q|\cdot|z|=|wz+qz|
$$

Answer (score 1):

$(w+q)z=wz+qz$ and |a||b|=|ab|